# Generating an event when button is pressed from web browser control to WPF

Tags: javascript, c#, html, wpf, webbrowser-control

I am trying to make an application that generates an event (any event) when a button is pressed in a HTML (web browser) control in WPF.
I have searched so far and tried various implementations but no luck. I am also attaching the most recent attempt, I was able to manipulate the values in html, read from html but no luck in getting an event when a button is pressed.

```
public void webBrowser_LoadCompleted()
    {

        HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument)webBrowser.Document;
        IHTMLElementCollection theElementCollection = doc.getElementsByTagName("input");


        foreach (IHTMLElement curElement in theElementCollection)
        {  

            string uiAuto = curElement.getAttribute("fname").ToString();
            if (uiAuto == "")
            {
                curElement.setAttribute("value", "changed value!");
            }
            if (uiAuto == "...")
            {
                curElement.setAttribute("value", "...");
            }
            if (curElement.getAttribute("value") == "Login")
            {
                curElement.click();
            }
        }

    }
```

The html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Testing HTML </title>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Hi there!</h1>

  <button type="button">Click Me!</button> 

<input type="text" value="login" id="fname" name="fname"><br>

<h2>Bye!</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

I am new to WPF and given this task to complete today. Just want to raise an event in my C# application when button is pressed in html along with some attributes, for example, data in textbox.

I also tried writing a javascript and using invokeScript() in webBrowser but that too didn't end up well.

Looking forward to some help, thank you.

Comment: No, It fails to fetch any event

Comment: "Generating an event"? What exactly do you want to do here? Respon to the button click?